# Ghostscript increases file size after split PDF

Tags: c#, image, pdf, ghostscript.net

I am splitting PDF file to Images and it is working fine, But issue is that I have PDF file it's size is 2.5 MB after splitting this file into images total size increases to 8 MB. So I don't want to increase these images size because this is storage issue on server.

**Code**

```
using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileSavePath))
{
    var imagelst = new Pdf2Image(fileSavePath).GetImages(1, pdfReader.NumberOfPages);
    foreach (var image in imagelst)
    {
        imageModal = new ImageModel();
        imageModal.FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
        image.Save(dirPath + "\\" + imageModal.FileName);       
        //Using below commented code I can decrease Image size 50 % percent but it creates Image quality problem. 
        //int newWidth = (int)(image.Width * 0.5);
        //int newHeight = (int)(image.Height * 0.5);
        //var newImage = ImageHelper.ResizeImage(image, newWidth, newHeight);
        //newImage.Save(dirPath + "\\" + imageModal.FileName);
        imageModelList.Add(imageModal);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "split to images"? Are you rasterizing it? What image type do you use, what colour depth, compression etc.? You might get more hints if you post the full ghostscript command and also describe what the input file contains - only black/white text? JPEG photos? All this would be relevant for your question,

Comment: Removing C# and asp.net-mvc tags because no sign of relevance.

Comment: @StefanHegny "Split to Images" means I have pdf file which contains number of pages and I am converting each page to Image. And I am saving it as png images. And this all things I am performing in C# with MVC Using Ghostscript.net

Comment: Please follow this link https://www.sejda.com/visually-combine-reorder-pdf I have done same thing. But only facing File size issue.

Comment: Won't look until I see your ghostscript parameters in the question... you could also briefly describe what's expected in the pdf

Comment: @StefanHegny Now please take a look

Comment: @Richard Sorry but i have to put C# tag

Comment: Hm, but now I don't see ghostscript but PdfReader, sorry never heard of that... maybe I should have stayed out of a .net thing from start - good luck

Comment: No problem: C# is now (after your edit) relevant.

Answer (score 1):

PDF files are vector descriptions of a page layout. Image files are bitmaps. One of the reasons vector descriptions are popular is **because** they are more compact than bitmaps.

If your bitmaps are too large then you can reduce the resolution at which you render them, obviously this reduces quality.

Other than that, your expectations seem unrealistic. An image file is almost always going to be larger than a vector file.